# rails post api json data passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4, post

Employee and Coupons are the 2 models with habtm associations, I want to send coupon_id and emp_id to join table. each employee can select multiple coupons, How to send this data from api.

```
 [{"emp_id" : 1, "coupon_id": 5 },{"emp_id" : 1, "coupon_id": 2 }]
```

Is this the proper way of sending data params? Each employee can select multiple coupons at a time, How can I pass the data and save in join table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
`gem 'active_model_serializers'` to custom your json response.

after install the  `'active_model_serializers'`:

`rails g serializer employee`
`rails g serializer coupon`

in `EmployeeSerializer`

```
class Employee < ActiveModelSerializers::Model
  attributes :id
  has_many: coupons
end
```

in `CouponSerializer`

```
class Coupon < ActiveModelSerializers::Model
  attributes :id      
end
```

from controller:

```
def emp_coupon
  @response = Employee.last
  render json: @response
end
```

this will return something like this `{id: 1, coupons: [{id: 2}, {id: 6}]}`

Comment: @Belinski, But same emp_id will repeats. Is there anyway we can keep emp_id constant {emp_id, {copon_id1, coupon_id2......}}

Comment: @belinski  {id: 1, coupons: [{id: 2}, {id: 6}]} if I pass this from api. How to save the data like Employee.save or Coupons.save to create records in join table

Comment: look in to nested_attributtes. You can set  each model, employee and coupon, to accept nested attributes for join table. Now you shoul to pass right params for each to controller

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `has_and_belongs_to_many`, First make sure you have created the join table `coupons_employees`.

This table will be automatically updated by active record once associated.
You don't have to manually update the join table.
I recommend you go through this [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#updating-the-schema)